# How to gzip individual files with maven and replace the original ones?

Tags: maven-2, ant

I need to gzip individual files that are part of my java project and replace the original file with the gzipped files.

So basically convert a directory /bla containing stylesheets, js, xml files to /bla with the same files but then all gzipped.

I can't find a simple way to do this with maven, please some advice?
I looked at the assembly plugin but that package files in to one gzip..
Should I use ant for this and run it from maven?
Ed

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any plugin which is capable of this. I would write the Ant and execute it with the [Maven Antrun Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

Answer (score 1):

The following blog post covers this topic: http://jorgetown.blogspot.com.br/2007/06/rhino-maven-automagic-compression.html

Alternatively you could use the YUI Compressor Maven plugin which also has an option to gzip compress the files.